# Permission is not showing on facebook login dialog

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-c#-sdk, c#-to-vb.net

Currently, I am working with facebook login using facebook c# SDK. Using this SDK I can successfully get the first name and last name however could not post to message to the wall.

My system gives me the exception -
(OAuthException - #200) (#200) The user hasn't authorized the application to perform this action.

then I have added extended permission and some more basic permission to my facebok application but it does not appear on the login dialog.

It will be a great help if any one give me any clue.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you passing the correct permission in the scope parameter when redirecting to the Facebook login dialog? Here is how I do it in my application:

```
FacebookClient fb = new FacebookClient();
string state = Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(fb.SerializeJson(new { returnUrl = returnUrl, csrf = csrfToken })));
fb.GetLoginUrl(new { 
    client_id = "APPID",
    client_secret = "APPSECRET",
    redirect_uri = "MYREDIRECTURL",
    response_type = "code",
    scope = "email,publish_stream,read_stream,manage_pages",
    state = state });
```

The permissions should be defined in the scope parameter. To post a message to the user's wall you need the "publish_stream" permission.